# Document not opening

Tags: 2010, document-library, document

I have a document library in Sharepoint 2010. When a click on a document, the following happens:

- The popup to open as read-only or edit comes up
- I choose readonly. Word opens but the document does not open
- There is just the word application empty (without a document loaded)

I think the issue could be security related. It happens on particular users only. For other users the log-in screen comes up again and they can open the document.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed - I just added the Sharepoint site to the trusted sites

Comment: Can you also please mark this as an answer, for future reference?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - will do so in 2 days as it does not allow me before 2 days.